# Why would the makemessages function for Django language localization ignore html files?

Tags: python, django, localization, internationalization

I am trying to run the Django language localization on a project, but makemessages always ignores the html templates in my templates folder.

I am running `python manage.py makemessages -a` from the project root, and all of the strings that are marked for translation inside `.py` files anywhere in the project are successfully added to the `.po` file.

Any of the strings in the html templates, i.e., `{{ trans "String_to_translate" }}` are ignored and not added to the .po file even though the necessary module is loaded at the top of the template, `{% load i18n %}`.

To test the possibility that the whole template folder was excluded from the makemessages function, I made a `.py` file and included a string for translation there, and it was successfully added to the `.po` file.

With all of that being said, does anyone know what could possibly be causing this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `templates` folder either needs to be in an app that has been listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` or in a directory that has been listed in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` - in your `settings.py` file

Comment: Both of those things are already configured, and the app works successfully with templates, except for the makemessages functionality on templates.

Comment: Say your django app is called `app`, there is a directory in that called `templates`?  This `.py` file you created, where was it?  Path?  How did you refer to it in the code?  Can you also paste the `INSTALLED_APPS` and `TEMPLATE_DIRS` settings here?

Comment: Inside of myproject/app, there is indeed a templates directory, and templates are successfully found from inside of it by any views that need templates. Makemessages successfully finds strings to translate inside the normal views.py, like ugettext("String_to_translate"). I also created example.py inside of the templates folder to check if makemessages ever looked inside of that folder for anything, and it found ugettext("Another string") inside of that. 
TEMPLATE_DIRS =('/home/dlmccoy/webapps/projectname/myproject/app/templates',), INSTALLED_APPS = (    
'myproject.app',
)

Comment: Wow, that's weird. Hard to say what the problem might be. You need to include `{% load i18n %}` in every template file, not just your "base" file that you are extending in your other template files. Are you doing that? Can you also remove the entry in `TEMPLATE_DIRS` (since the directory will be picked up if it is inside your app directory)?

Comment: For the sake of testing, I set up a template without any importing of base files, and still no luck. I do include {% load i18n %} every time. I also removed the entry for TEMPLATE_DIRs with no change. In case this is also useful information, I tried manually editing the django.po file with translations, and the template still can't find them with {{ trans "String_to_translate" }}. Any other ideas?

Comment: Nope, sorry, no other ideas.  Maybe you should put up a test case on bitbucket/github. Given the available information, I can't think of anything else.

Comment: In one of the dumbest syntax errors in web programming, the solution was to write {% trans "String_to_translate %} rather than {{ trans "String_to_translate" }}. Thanks for putting up with me, rm.

Comment: Hmm, should have noticed that. The weirdest bugs usually end up being caused by something like this.

Answer (score 4):

Try creating symlink for your `templates` folder in your `app` folder. Then call makemessages from your app folder with symlink switch `django-admin.py makemessages --all --symlinks`

```
cd /myproject
ln -s /myproject/templates /myproject/myapp/templates    
cd /myproject/myapp
django-admin.py makemessages --all --symlinks
```

`makemessages` ignores `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `INSTALLED_APPS`. Templates dir needs to be inside your app folder and `makemessages` needs to be called from inside your app folder.

Answer (score 0):

Change the syntax of `{{ trans "string" }}` to `{% trans "string" %}`.

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7054082/2) to the question [Why would the makemessages function for Django language localization ignore html files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054082/why-would-the-makemessages-function-for-django-language-localization-ignore-html) by the OP [dlmccoy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/893480/dlmccoy) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>

Comment: That sounds like a typo to me...