# Not Able to create django.po

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-i18n

I am new to django web app,

my project structure looks like:
x
  ->x
  ->settings.py

in settings.py I have following entry:

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
LOCALE_PATHS = ( 
join (BASE_DIR, 'locale'), 
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', _('English')),
    #('en-us', ugettext('English US')),
    ('es', _('Spanish')),
    ('en-Gb', _('English UK')),
)

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True
```

I have installed get text on my MAC OSX 10.7.5

in my template:

```
{% load i18n %}
{% trans "Login To UI Mirror" %}
```

Using the below command

```
django-admin.py makemessages -a
```

seems its able to generate `django.po`

but it is missing with

message id defined in template.

here is what it has:

```
#: settings.py:156
msgid "English"
msgstr ""

#: settings.py:158
msgid "Spanish"
msgstr ""

#: settings.py:159
msgid "English UK"
msgstr ""
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Template Codes:

```
_base.html:

{% load compress %}
{% load i18n %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        {# Mobile meta tag #}
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="True">
        <meta name="MobileOptimized" content="320">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
        <meta http-equiv="cleartype" content="on">
        {# Favicons #}
        <link rel="icon" href="{{static}}images/uimirror.ico" type="image/x-icon">
        {% block title %}
            {% include "core/_title.html" with location='lgn_reg' %}
        {% endblock title %}

        {# Tile icon for Win8 (144x144 + tile color) #}
        {% block css_media %}
            {% include "core/_media.html" with location='lgn_reg' %}
        {% endblock css_media %}
    </head>

    <body>
        {% block content %}

        {% endblock content %}

        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        {% block script_media %}
            {% include "core/_script_media.html" with location='lgn' %}
        {% endblock script_media %}

    </body>
</html>
```

1st extend:

```
login_register.html

{% extends 'core/_base.html' %}

{% block css_media %}
    {% include "core/_media.html" with location=location %}
{% endblock css_media %}

{% block content %}
    <div class="uimmaincontainer" id="uimmaincontainer">
    {% include "core/login_register/_login_register_theme.html" with location=location %}
    {% include "core/login_register/_login.html" with location=location%}
    {% include "core/login_register/_register.html" with location=location%}
    </div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Trans block :

```
_login_register_theme.html

{% load i18n %}
<div class="pt15 {% if location == 'lgn' %} active {% else %} hidden {% endif %}" id="_ui_lgn_them">
    <h4 aria-hidden="true" class="">
        <img width="15" height="15" alt=""
            src="#"
            class="uiHeaderImage img">{% trans "Login To UI Mirror" %}
    </h4>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <div class="mb5 uiHeaderSubTitle f-left fsm tc-3">Enter to the most existing virtual world.</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does your settings.py contains :
    TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
        'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
        'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )

?

Comment: Sorry, I have no more idea, then. Have you look this question ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7054082/why-would-the-makemessages-function-for-django-language-localization-ignore-html

Comment: One more things, when I run the application it says : Invalid block tag: 'trans', even though i have {% load i18n %} in _base.html…might be I am missing something

Comment: In the question I linked in my previous comment, one guy suggest to add {% load i18n %} in every template the final template inherit from.

Comment: Oh, and if your template extends another one, maybe you simply have to put your `{% trans %}` statement inside a block that exists in the parent template ?

Comment: Ok thank you..template error got resolved by adding load i18n thanks for pointing out..but still make message is not generating

Comment: Can you edit yourq uestion and paste your whole template code ?

Comment: Done, Please have a look

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46366/discussion-between-eliot-berriot-and-jayaram-pradhan)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a problem with your template directory structure. [Django template loader](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader) is looking for a directory called "templates" within your app.

Your templates are located under `core/login_register/`, so django can't find them.

You can use the following structure for your templates :

```
└── yourapp
    └── templates
        └── yourapp 
            ├── base.html
            └── index.html
```

This way, django will find your templates, and you'll even be able to override these templates in other apps :

```
└── yourapp
    └── templates
        └── yourapp 
            ├── base.html
            └── index.html
└── anotherapp
    └── templates
        └── yourapp 
            ├── base.html # it will override the template yourapp/templates/yourapp/base.html
```

It's a [common structure for django projects](https://oncampus.oberlin.edu/webteam/2012/09/architecture-django-templates).